# Can TokBox handle multiple microphones

Tags: tokbox

I'm trying to connect multiple microphones to my web app.

But I haven't been able to get TokBox to list more than one microphone.

I am using the computer's built-in mike, plus my smartphone's mike as a secondary microphone, via DroidCam.

Can TokBox handle multiple microphones on the same computer?

If possible, can I do this with DroidCam? If not, how can I connect multiple (three) microphones and select them on TokBox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know that tokbox provides this directly but you could potentially use MultiStreamsMixer

https://github.com/muaz-khan/MultiStreamsMixer

```
const audioMixer = new MultiStreamsMixer([microphone1, microphone2]);
const mixedStream = audioMixer.getMixedStream();
```

and then give the tokbox publisher (via setAudioSource) the mixed stream.